# Question about furniture making and scripts in Second Life?

Tags: scripting, linden-scripting-language

Okay, so I just recently started messing with furniture making. I know a little bit about making stuff and scripting but I wouldn’t call myself a pro just yet. Anyway, I’m using the Mizzy's Furniture Script (whole sale version) to add the animations to my furniture. I really like the whole set up with it but there’s a problem I’m having and that’s getting the position right. I found a scripted called Pos Rot Determinator script which is supposed to tell me the position of my avie. Well the issue is even with that I’m still having issues with positioning the animations. The Mizzy’s Furniture Script wants something like this <0.55, 0, -0.40> and when I use the Pos Rot Determinator I get something like this <0.3343345, 0.0000, 0.45433> do I need to round the number off to the nearest whole number or something? I’m not a math genius so this is really giving me a headache, lol. Any help, tips, advice or anything would be helpful before I start pulling my hair out!! I paid a good amount of L’s for the Mizzy’s Furniture Script and I would really like to use it without the hassle of sitting, standing up, sitting and standing up again to get the correct position!

Comment: I never thought I'd see a 'furniture' tag on SO...

Comment: lol that really doesn't answer my question....

Comment: What you need to do is start a virtual SO in Second Life and ask your question there.  :-)

Comment: @ire_and_curses: It actually happen three times! Surprise. And now it's gone.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about rounding..put in the numbers that your Determinator is giving you.   LSL takes several decimal points of precision -- it's just your Determinator is being a bit more precise than the example

Comment: okay thanks...just having a lot of issues with this script found one that was easier to use but it doesn't do well with multiple animations... :-(